# A question about truth tables

Tags: boolean-algebra

Hello guys i have a question, 
I am trying to make a truth table which consists out of 4 variables 
F(A,B,C,D) = B'D + A'D + BD
Is it true on the truth table when for example in B'D we have 0001 or 1001 so B' just needs to be
 0 and D = 1 ? 
and on A'D  A needs to be 0 and d = 1  
so the 0111 and 0011 is true for A'D? 
I hope i made my point clear thanks!!

Comment: I'm sorry what?

Comment: Is there no meant to be no $C$ on the RHS of your function equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simplifying first?
$$\require{cancel}F(A,B,C,D) = \underbrace{\overline{B}D + BD}_{D\cancelto1{(B+\overline{B})}} + \overline{A}D=\underbrace{D+\overline{A}D}_{D\cancelto1{(\overline{A}+1)}}=D$$

So your truth table will always have $F=1$ when $D=1$, and $F=0$ when $D=0$.

Because I'm bored anyway, here's your truth table:
$$\begin{array}{cccc|c}
A & B & C & D & F\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{array}$$